# I keep getting this error in CSS and I don't know why

Tags: html, css, error-handling

I keep getting this error in css. This screenshot is on dreamweaver. I have also tried on brackets and codesandbox. Nothing seems to be working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbIeU.png)

Comment: you use scss syntax instead css syntax (means you have to apply each class/element name/id  in its block `{}` and not one inside each other)

Comment: hmm seems that your IDE doesnt recognize SCSS ?

Comment: @ahmed75 see example here:https://jsfiddle.net/pfczbvg3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question you are using a valid SASS or SCSS with nested classes in a .css file and hence the error is shown. You can use this link to convert SASS to CSS: [SassMeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/)

The equivalent css would be:

```
header {
  display: flex;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: #A7ACB1;
}
header nav {
  flex: l;
}
header nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Please use "code samples" in the editor to post your questions for the code snippet going forward.